# Which Apache CXF interceptor phase is for schema validation?

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, interceptor, phase

I have an interceptor, for inbound responses to my client, that runs in the pre-logical phase of an apache cxf 2.7 jax-ws app.  That interceptor logs the soap envelope body to a file as a string; no marshalling involved.  When the request and response are fine, it works great.  But when the response fails to pass schema validation, the interceptor does not create a new file.  So I'm guessing the pre-logical phase happens after the schema validation but I have not found any good docs describing all the phases and order of processing.  What is the phase just before schema validation?   http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Answer (score 0):

Just now found this...   http://www.mastertheboss.com/images/stories/ws/interceptors.png

I will also try to temporarily turn off schema validation for this client.